# distribute tensorflow demos

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Recently, tensorflow had add the distribute training module, what's the distribute pre-requirement? I mean the environment like this,

```
tensorflow >= 0.8 kubernates shared file system, gcloud?
```

And it had release the example code:

Is there any way to run tensorflow cluster example, when only have hdfs and without any shared file system, where will model file store in?

Comment: your question makes me think you haven't even read the very short [description page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Each computer will need to have tensorflow installed, (and in my experience, they should all be the same version.  I had a few issues mixing versions 8 and 9).
Once that is set up, each computer will need access to the code it is to run (main.py for example).  We use an NFS to share this, but you could just as easily git pull on each machine to get the latest copy of your code.
Then you just need to start them up.  We would just ssh to each machine in our most basic setup, but if you have a cluster like kubernates, then it may be different for you.

As for checkpoints, I believe only the chief worker writes to checkpoint files if that's what your last question was asking.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: If you need a full demo that works out of the box, I can post one on the Documentation page here at SO later this week/early next week.